# Decomposition of Shannon conditional mutual information as seen on Wikipedia [Solved]

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I am looking for a proof for a formula seen on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mutual_information):

\begin{align}
I(X;Y|Z) & = H(Z|X) + H(X) + H(Z|Y) + H(Y) - H(Z|X,Y) - H(X,Y) - H(Z) \\
{} & = I(X;Y) + H(Z|X) + H(Z|Y) - H(Z|X,Y) - H(Z)
\end{align}

I checked the ref given on Wiki but couldn't find the formula in it.

Thank you!

Comment: Note that $H(Z|X) - H(Z) = -I(X;Z)$, and $H(Z|Y) - H(Z|X,Y) = I(Z;X|Y)$. Consequently, the above relation is $I(X;Y|Z) \overset{?}= I(X;Y) + I(X;Z|Y) - I(X;Z)$, which is easy to show by expanding $I(X;Y,Z)$ by the chain rule in two different ways.

Comment: Thank you for teaching me humility :-).